# Powershell MySQL string return | to html?

Tags: mysql, string, powershell, variables

I have a MySQL connection with powershell that returns string values. It iterates through the return just fine- without my connection info here is the simple return (0....4) are the colums to return based off MySQL query:

```
    $dr3.GetString(0) 
    $dr3.GetString(1)
    $dr3.GetString(2)
    $dr3.GetString(3)
    $dr3.GetString(4)
```

My question is how to iterate through these results to generate a email report. The results return- this works great. For the sake of example say each of the above strings return 5 rows. I want to display these five rows in a table (hash or convertto-html or other...) and pass the "variable" of the new element/hash to a send-mailmessage command to generate a daily emailed report. So far I can only get the first return to print- e.g. $dr3.GetString(0) prints "Dave". I can get the first row of every column to print fine to a variable but am wondering if I am missing a foreach loop coupled with a convertto-html table in here somewhere....I know there must be something with iteration and convertto-html that I am missing! Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you know the names of the columns, try something like $dr3 | select-object -property Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4 | convertto-html

Comment: They are returned as strings from mysql, I cannot treat them like powershell objects im thinking...I tried this and a print of $dr3.firstname did not have a return.

Comment: Is this a datarow object?  The naming would make me think so.

Comment: yes- at this point I don't even care to convertto-html...if I can store the foreach loop in a variable I can format around any problems.  `       $var1 =  $dr3.GetString(0) 
       foreach  ($result1 in $var1){
            write "$result1"
            }` this doesn't work either- this will allow me to print $result1 and see all the names on the console....but not allow those to be written to a variable for later use with a send-mailmessage command.

Comment: What output does $dr3 | get-member give you? I would expect to see the columns listed as properties at the end

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer that works for my use case. Instead of using convertto-html, I am just using html fragmenting and string pasting. Below is my code and this works like a charm:

```
while ($dr3.Read())
{  

$dr3.GetString(0)          
$dr3.GetString(1)
$dr3.GetString(2)
$dr3.GetString(3)
$dr3.GetString(4)


 #build html table foreach  array
$html = "<table><tr><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td></tr>"
foreach ($result in $dr3)
{ 
    $html += "<tr><td>" + $dr3.GetString(0) + "</td><td>" +         $dr3.GetString(1) + "</td></tr>"
}
$html += "</table>"
```

This is sort of a roundabout way of getting there....but this works. Thanks for the ideas- they got the wheels turning Mike.